# How to append and prepend to every line in each text file in directory?

Tags: python

I've come up with this code in Python which takes a text file in directory and prepends and appends input to every line. Here it is:

```
prefix = '111'
suffix = '222'

with open('source.txt', 'r') as src:
    with open('dest.txt', 'w') as dest:
       for line in src:
           dest.write('%s%s%s\n' % (prefix, line.rstrip('\n'), suffix))
```

---

So, I want to do the same type of thing, but instead, I have in the directory a bunch of txt files each containing several hundred lines.

And I want it to append and prepend (like above) to each line in each file in that directory.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show the dictionary. Why can't you replace `'source.txt'` with the file in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
directory = '/path/to/directory/'
prefix = '111'
suffix = '222'
# list comprehension for all files with a .txt extension
txt_files = [
  f
  for f in os.listdir(directory)
  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f)) and '.txt' in f
]
for txt in txt_files:
  with open(os.path.join(directory, txt), 'r') as src:
    # writing file to same name with added .dest extension
    with open(os.path.join(directory, txt + '.dest', 'w') as dest:
      for line in src:
        dest.write('%s%s%s\n' % (prefix, line, suffix))
```

I am assuming you want to do other things to these files; otherwise it would be much simpler to do the same thing using `find` and `sed`.